# time and distance problem related to speed

Tags: arithmetic

**2 workers,One Young And One Old, Live Together and Work at the same office . It takes 20 mins for the young man to walk to office . the old man takes 30 mins for the same distance. when will the young man catch up with the old man , if the old man starts at 10.00 am and the young man starts at 10.05 am ?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you edit your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

From the condition we know that the old man passes $\frac {1}{30}$ of the way in 1 minute. So in 5 minutes, he'll pass $\frac{1}{6}$.

So we could think of the problem like this. They both start at the same time, but the old man need to pass $\frac{5}{6}$ of the way, while the young man should walk whole way. We aleady know that the old man pass $\frac 1{30}$ of the way in a minute, while the young man pass $\frac 1{20}$ of the way in a minute. So we need to find solution to the following equation:

$$1-\frac 1{20} t = \frac 56 - \frac1{30} t$$
$$1- \frac 56 = \left(\frac 1{20} - \frac 1{30}\right)t$$
$$\frac 16 = \frac 1{60} t \implies t = 10$$

So they'll meet 10 minutes after the young man starts his journey, i.e in $10:15 am$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r_y =$ rate of the young man

$r_o =$ rate of the old man

$d = $distance to the office

Then $r_y = d/20 minutes$ and $r_o = d/30 minutes$

Now, let $t_y =$ time that the young man travels after 10:05

$t_o = $time that the old man travels after 10:00

Since the distance that the young man travels is the same as the distance that the old man travels (as they meet up), then

$r_yt_y = r_ot_o$

But $t_0 = t_y + 5 minutes$

So, $r_o(t_y+5) = r_y*t_y$

And $r_o/r_y = (d/30)/(d/20) = 2/3 = t_y/(t_y+5)$

Then you just solve for $t_y$ and add it to 10:05 to get the time they meet up.

Answer (score 0):

Let the distance be $d$ KM

So, the speed of the younger worker is  $\frac d{20}$ KM/minute and that of the older person is $\frac d{30}$ KM/minute

So, in $t$ minutes the young man will cover $\frac d{20}t$ KM

But, by that time, the old man will get $(t+5)$ minutes as he has left $5$ minutes earlier, when he will cover $\frac d{30}(t+5)$ KM

The young man catch up with the old man , if the distance covered by them are same

Answer (score 0):

distance b/w office and room be x
speed of young man x/20 
speed of old man x/30
relative speed x/20-x/30=x/60
distance traveled by old man in 5 min =(x/30)*5
                                       =x/6
so young man have to manage only the x/6 distance =(x/6)/x/60
                                                  =10 min
so they will meet in 10:15 time

Comment: It would make a better impact if you format your answers using MathJax